# Convergence in measure, a few questions.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

So I have a few questions on convergence in measure (Lebesgue measure)

So we know that convergence on measure is induced by the norm $$d(f,g)=\int_E \frac{|f-g|}{1+|f-g|}$$ on finite measure $E$

Thus, we know that if $f_n$'s every sub-sequence has a convergent sub-sequence, then the sequence converges since we are on a topological space, correct? Are there any other neat facts about convergence in measure that can be deduced from the fact the we have a normed vector space?

Also on finite measure it can be shown that $f_n \to f$ in measure $\iff$ every sub-sequence has a further sub-sequence that converges a.e. Does this simply follow from the preceding observation? As pointwise implies in measrue on finite measure space?

Is this the standard proof ?:

Assume that $f_n \not \to f$, then $\lambda(|f_{n_k}-f|\geq \delta)\geq \epsilon$ for some $\delta,\epsilon$ and all $k$. But now we can pick a subsequence of $f_{n_k}$ that  converges a.e and by egorof we know it converges in measure. Thus we contradict $\lambda(|f_{n_k}-f|\geq \delta)\geq \epsilon$

Answer (score 3):

Once you know convergence in measure is equivalent to convergence in that metric, every familiar fact about metric spaces is fair game.

However, do note that $d$ is a metric, not a norm. And $\|f\|:=d(f,0)$ is not a norm because scalars don't factor out properly. So, convergence in measure is metrizable, not necessarily normable.

To see that there is no norm on $L^1$ such that convergence in that norm is equivalent to convergence in measure, we can argue as follows:

Consider Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. By a theorem of Nikodym there is no continuous linear functional $\phi: (L^1([0,1]),d)\to \mathbb{R}$ except for the identically $0$ one. For a (sketch of) a proof, see Bogachev's *Measure Theory*, volume 1, exercise 4.7.61 on page 306. By the Hahn-Banach theorem, the metric topology induced by $d$ cannot be induced by a norm, and thus neither can convergence in measure.

Comment: Are my observations correct? Thank you for pointing out that is not a norm!